# Orthogonality in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I want to prove that if for all $x,y\in H$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$ 
$$\|x+\alpha y\|=\|x-\alpha y\|,$$
then $x\perp y$. I was able to show that Re$(x,y)=0$. Any ideas on how to show that Im$(x,y)=0$?

Comment: Show that $\operatorname{Re} \, (x, iy) = 0$.

Comment: Have I done some typos, or if you square the equality on both sides you immediately get $$2(\alpha+\overline{\alpha})\langle x,y\rangle=0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\alpha=1$, we have
$$
\langle x+\alpha y, x+\alpha y\rangle = \|y\|^2 + 2 \Re\langle x,y  \rangle + \|x\|^2\\
\langle x-\alpha y, x-\alpha y\rangle = \|y\|^2 - 2 \Re\langle x,y  \rangle + \|x\|^2
$$
If $\alpha = i$, we have
$$
\langle x+\alpha y, x+\alpha y\rangle = \|y\|^2 + 2 \Im\langle x,y  \rangle + \|x\|^2\\
\langle x-\alpha y, x-\alpha y\rangle = \|y\|^2 - 2 \Im\langle x,y  \rangle + \|x\|^2
$$